# Error Printing Foreign Key ID. Symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: symfony, foreign-keys, doctrine-orm, twig, one-to-many

I have an Entity called Keyword, and it has two rows:

```
id  comment_id  foo_id  text
2       1         1     Jajajaja :) Hola.
3       2         1     Chao
```

foo_id and comment_id are foreign keys and integer values. Foo_id from table Foo and comment_id from table Comments.

I'm trying to print comment_id and foo_id in a twig template.

```
{% for k in keywords %}
    {{ k.id}} , {{ k.text}}, {{ k.comment }}, {{ k.foo}}
{% else %}
```

but it gives me this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class 
Proxies\PruebasRBundleEntityCommentsProxy could not be 
converted to string in       C:\wamp\www\sym\app\cache\dev\twig\52\c9\3138bf2dc905760b186f2d006484.php 
line 74") in PruebasRBundle:Default:keywords.html.twig at line 24.
```

So, I tried printing the values that are not Foreign keys

I'm trying to print comment_id and foo_id in a twig template.

```
{% for k in keywords %}
    {{ k.id}} , {{ k.text}} <!--No k.comment no k.foo -->
{% else %}
```

it works this way, but I can't print foreign keys values and I need them.

It makes me think that there's something with the relationships :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Doctrine automatically detects the k.comment foreign key, and returns you an **object** representing the foreign comment row.

This object is a PruebasRBundle\Entity\Comments instance. (Doctrine2 will wrap it in a proxy to ease lazy loading).

Your problem is that you try to cast this object as a **string**.

Etiher modify your twig like this:

```
{% for k in keywords %}
    {{ k.id}} , {{ k.text}}, {{ k.comment.id }}, {{ k.foo}}
{% else %}
```

Or implement the `__toString` method in your `Comment` class.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know any of what you're saying. Didn't read that in any documentation. Do you know how would a print a variable like this k.comment.id but in a php template? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the numeric values try this way:

```
{% for k in keywords %}
    {{ k.id}} , {{ k.text}}, {{ k.comment_id }}, {{ k.foo_id}}
{% else %}
```

If you want to print some value from related entities try creating a [magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) __toString() for entities Foo and Comments. Then:

```
{% for k in keywords %}
    {{ k.id}} , {{ k.text}}, {{ k.comments }}, {{ k.foo}}
{% else %}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and it doesn't work. 
Also, when I query for all records like this: $keywords = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PruebasRBundle:Keywords')->findAll(); it finds all elements. But when I find by Id it says No records...and I'm sure the Id exists.